# Is there a way to force a method to inherit a scope from it's caller?

Tags: c#

If I have a method outside it's callers scope that does a few things, and I have to call this method multiple times in multiple places. Is there any way to make the entire scope of the caller available to the method without passing parameters and also without using global variables?  Like if I need it to have an access to a List, an entity framework context

Instead of

```
myMethod(string _string, List<string> _stringList, EntityContext _db)
{
    //log _string to a database table
    //add _string to _stringList
    //etc.
}
```

Is there a way I can just pass the `_string` and make the method inherit the scope as if I'm just writing the same three lines of code everywhere I call this method?  It seems a lot cleaner to call `myMethod("foo")` than `myMethod("foo", stringList, MyEntities)`.

I could create a class, instantiate it, and call the class, but I'm just plain curious if scope inheritance or scope passing is a thing.

Comment: "without passing parameters and without using global variables" other than using static stuff (which essentially is a global variable), no.

Comment: If you intend on calling the same method multiple times from the same caller method, you can define a local method that captures context in a closure and then call the local method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely don't do that. If you have a context you need to pass, use a class to represent the context needed, but don't try to handwave it away and hide it. It makes for unmaintainable code full of interdependencies.

In fact, the "bother" or "overhead" of passing the context object around is a good thing: it points out that having dependencies between the elements of your software project is not free. If you think that writing out the extra parameter is "too much work", then you're missing the forest for the trees: the *dependency* thus introduced has a much higher mental overhead than the mere mechanics of typing an extra parameter. After you pass that context a few times, typing it will be second nature and have 0 real overhead. The typing is cheap and doesn't require thinking, but keeping in mind the dependency and how it figures in the design of the overall system is anything but.

So: if you are trying to argue that introducing the dependency is worth it, then you have to back it up with actions and actually pass the context object around. The real cost is in the dependency, not the typing. Otherwise, it's a case of "talk is cheap" :)

One way of decreasing the apparent "cost" of passing such context objects is to upset the balance and make the context object actually do something, besides just carrying data. You would then use the context object to manipulate the objects for you, instead of calling the methods on the objects. This sort of "inversion" is quite handy, and often results in better design. After all, the presence of the context indicates that there's an overarching common state, and that perhaps too much functionality is delegated to the "end object", making it intertwined with the common state, whereas it may make more sense in the context object, making the end object less dependent on the presence of any particular external state.

You'd want the context to have methods that require "seeing the big picture", i.e. being aware of the presence of multiple objects, whereas the "leaf objects" (the ones with `myMethod`) should have methods that don't require the context, or that are general enough not to force any particular context class.

In your case, `myMethod` perhaps instead of working directly on an `EntityContext` could generate a functor or a similar action-wrapping object that performs the action, and this could then be applied by the caller (e.g. the context) to execute the database action. This way later it'll be easier to centrally manage the queue of database operations, etc.

When I refactor large projects, this sort of a "context inversion" comes in handy often, and the need for such patterns is very common. Usually, as large projects grow, the "leaf classes" start up lean, and end up acquiring functionality that belongs at a higher level. This is why using good tooling to explore the history of the repository is an imperative, and it's equally important that the entire repository history is available, i.e. that it was properly imported to git. I personally use [DeepGit](https://www.syntevo.com/deepgit/) to trace the history of the code I work on, and find such tool indispensable. DeepGit is free as in beer for any use, and if you're not using a tool with similar functionality, you're seriously missing out, I think.

The need to pass contexts around is usually the indicator that a higher level has to be designed and introduced, and the "leafs" then need to be slimmed down, their context-using functionality moved out into the higher level. A few years down the road yet another higher level ends up being needed, although there are projects so far gone that when you just refactor them to make sense of the code base, two or three additional layers make themselves apparent!

Answer (score 0):

I know of 2 ways that can be done. Consider you have the following method:

```
    static void myMethod(string _stringA, string _stringB, string _stringC)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{_stringA},{_stringB},{_stringC}");
    }
```

1. Create an overload method in the class. For example you could create an overloaded method like:

   ```
    static void myMethod(string _stringA)
    {
        myMethod(_stringA, "stringB", "stringC");
    }
   ```
2. The second way **(which I would not advice it)** is doing it the functional way like Javascript does (by using delegates):

   ```
    public delegate void MethodDelegate(string _string);
    static MethodDelegate mMethod1;
    static MethodDelegate mMethod2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mMethod1 = delegate (string s) { myMethod(s, "method1-str-a", "method1-str-b"); };
        mMethod1("str1");
        mMethod2 = delegate (string s) { myMethod(s, "method2-str-a", "method2-str-b"); };
        mMethod2("str2");
    }
   ```